# How to create an Array, ArrayList, Stack and Queue in Java?

Tags: java, data-structures, declaration

I was reading a Java article, but found no differences in the declaration and was confused over. Can anyone list me out this?

Added the Article

http://www.theparticle.com/javadata2.html

Comment: This is a very outdated article: "All the source has been compiled and tested using JDK v1.2" JDK 1.6 is the current stable release.

Comment: so what, the data structers wont change regardless of the version of language changes.

Comment: Please elaborate your confusion in more detail. What was the expectation? What was the unexpectation? Also "no differences in declaration" is too ambiguous. Please elaborate more.

Answer (score 72, accepted):

Without more details as to what the question is exactly asking, I am going to answer the title of the question,

Create an [`Array`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Array.htm):

```
String[] myArray = new String[2];
int[] intArray = new int[2];

// or can be declared as follows
String[] myArray = {"this", "is", "my", "array"};
int[] intArray = {1,2,3,4};
```

Create an [`ArrayList`](http://leepoint.net/notes-java/data/collections/lists/arraylist.html):

```
ArrayList<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("Hello");
myList.add("World");

ArrayList<Integer> myNum = new ArrayList<Integer>();
myNum.add(1);
myNum.add(2);
```

This means, create an `ArrayList` of `String` and `Integer` objects. You ***cannot*** use `int` because thats a [primitive data types](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html), see the link for a list of primitive data types.

Create a [`Stack`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Stackdatastructure.htm):

```
Stack myStack = new Stack();
// add any type of elements (String, int, etc..)
myStack.push("Hello");
myStack.push(1);
```

Create an [`Queue`](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Collections-Data-Structure/Queuedatastructure.htm): (*using LinkedList*)

```
Queue<String> myQueue = new LinkedList<String>();
Queue<Integer> myNumbers = new LinkedList<Integer>();
myQueue.add("Hello");
myQueue.add("World");
myNumbers.add(1);
myNumbers.add(2);
```

Same thing as an `ArrayList`, this declaration means create an `Queue` of `String` and `Integer` objects.

---

#### Update:

In response to your comment from the other given answer,

> i am pretty confused now, why are using string. and what does `<String>` means

We are using `String` only as a pure example, but you can add any other *object*, but the main point is that you use an *object* ***not*** a primitive type. Each primitive data type has their own [primitive wrapper class](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Primitive_wrapper_class), see link for list of primitive data type's wrapper class.

I have posted some links to explain the difference between the two, but here are a list of primitive types

- `byte`
- `short`
- `char`
- `int`
- `long`
- `boolean`
- `double`
- `float`

Which means, you are not allowed to make an `ArrayList` of integer's like so:

```
ArrayList<int> numbers = new ArrayList<int>(); 
           ^ should be an object, int is not an object, but Integer is!
ArrayList<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            ^ perfectly valid
```

Also, you can use your own objects, here is my `Monster` object I created,

```
public class Monster {
   String name = null;
   String location = null;
   int age = 0;

public Monster(String name, String loc, int age) { 
   this.name = name;
   this.loc = location;
   this.age = age;
 }

public void printDetails() {
   System.out.println(name + " is from " + location +
                                     " and is " + age + " old.");
 }
}
```

Here we have a `Monster` object, but now in our `Main.java` class we want to keep a record of all our `Monster`'s that we create, so let's add them to an `ArrayList`

```
public class Main {
    ArrayList<Monster> myMonsters = new ArrayList<Monster>();

public Main() {
    Monster yetti = new Monster("Yetti", "The Mountains", 77);
    Monster lochness = new Monster("Lochness Monster", "Scotland", 20);

    myMonsters.add(yetti); // <-- added Yetti to our list
    myMonsters.add(lochness); // <--added Lochness to our list
  
    for (Monster m : myMonsters) {
        m.printDetails();
     }
   }

public static void main(String[] args) {
    new Main();
 }
}
```

(*I helped my girlfriend's brother with a Java game, and he had to do something along those lines as well, but I hope the example was well demonstrated*)

Comment: You can't use `int` but you would have to use `Integer`, when you use `< >` notation, it expects a *class* (`Integer`) not a primitive type (`int`)

Comment: Thats a great riposte, thanks for your wee. Can you show me your example of monster class running with ArrayList or any other so that i can see the full code. 

Thanks

Comment: My code snippet shows how I used an `ArrayList` with my `Monster` class, I am not quite sure which other code you wanted to see.

Comment: I can't post the whole project, theres 9-10 classes and one abstract class, but what you have now should be good enough as a running example, if not each data structure in question, I have linked to examples.

Comment: Thanks, i was not asking for the entire project. you created a class monster, now calling the monster class in another class and then using the instance there. I just wanted to know how you would have done it, as it would have been made me more strong.

Thanks a lot for your time,

Comment: @theband, I edited my answer to provide, what I hope to be, is a running version. There is `Monster` class and a `Main` class.

Comment: Loch Ness monser is 20 years old? ha

Comment: @Rubys, I wanted to make him younger, he's self conscience about that.

Comment: It is not advisable to use the Stack class in java since it is based off of legacy Vectors. 

From the [java docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Stack.html) for the class: 
_A more complete and consistent set of LIFO stack operations is provided by the Deque interface and its implementations, which should be used in preference to this class_
`Deque<Integer> stack = new ArrayDeque<Integer>();`

Comment: FYI `public class LinkedList<E>  extends AbstractSequentialList<E>
 implements List<E>, Deque<E>, Cloneable, java.io.Serializable { //stuff } ` we can use `LinkedList` as Queue, PriorityQueue, Dequeue too.

Comment: And `public class Stack<E> extends Vector<E> { //stuff } ` code - http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/Stack.java#Stack.peek%28%29    Note - it has only 5 public method.

Comment: Why do you use `LinkedList<>()` after `Queue<>`?

Answer (score 2):

I am guessing you're confused with the parameterization of the types:

```
// This works, because there is one class/type definition in the parameterized <> field
ArrayList<String> myArrayList = new ArrayList<String>(); 


// This doesn't work, as you cannot use primitive types here
ArrayList<char> myArrayList = new ArrayList<char>();
```

Comment: i am pretty confused now, why are using string. and what does <String> means

Comment: @theband, I had updated my answer to hopefully clear up some confusion, if you have any other questions regarding it, I will be more than happy to help.

Comment: @Kevin The part where it says <String> means that you are creating an ArrayList whose elements are all of type String.

Answer (score 1):

Just a small correction to the first answer in this thread.

Even for Stack, you need to create new object with generics if you are using Stack from java util packages.

```
Right usage:
    Stack<Integer> s = new Stack<Integer>();
    Stack<String> s1 = new Stack<String>();

    s.push(7);
    s.push(50);

    s1.push("string");
    s1.push("stack");
```

if used otherwise, as mentioned in above post, which is:

```
    /*
    Stack myStack = new Stack();
    // add any type of elements (String, int, etc..)
    myStack.push("Hello");
    myStack.push(1);
    */
```

Although this code works fine, has unsafe or unchecked operations which results in error.