# How to import a text file in a boolean method java

Tags: java, boolean, text-files

I am writing a boolean method in which I need to return True if the text file is imported successfully. I also need to be able to access each String and int per line individually. So if the text file contains something like:

1 North  East Baker St

I want to return the True and be able to access the 1, the North, and the East Baker St individually. The text file is also multiple lines so I don't know if that changes anything. Thanks.

This is what I have so far. I can't get it to compile and don't know if im on the right path.

```
 String nameFile = "";

 public boolean readFile(String filename)
 {
  nameFile = filename;
  FileReader file = new FileReader(nameFile);
  BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(file);

  String text = "";
  String line = reader.readLine();
  while (line != null)
  {
     text += line;
     line = reader.readLine();
  }

  System.out.println(text);


}
```

Comment: did you try anything yet?

Comment: Yes, I added what I have done so far. I thought I did when I posted it but seems I forgot.

Comment: Will you have this spaces and format of the string throughout your text file? I mean the number (1), first word after the number (North) and the rest of the string (East Baker St)? or woud you mind adding any separators like this "1@North@East Baker St" to your text strings?

Comment: I plan on just having spaces between each

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this example.

```
 public class StreetHandling {

    List<Integer> number;
    List<String> firstWord;
    List<String> rest;

    public StreetHandling() {
        number = new ArrayList();
        firstWord = new ArrayList();
        rest = new ArrayList();
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

         StreetHandling sh = new StreetHandling();
         System.out.println("Read file : "+sh.finishReadFile("streets.txt"));

         //you can use the lists anyway you want from here

    }

    public boolean finishReadFile(String fname) {
         boolean finishRead = false;
         try {
              FileReader file = new FileReader(fname);
              BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(file);
              String s = "";
              String arr[] = null;
              while (br.ready()) {
                 s = br.readLine().trim();
                 arr = s.split(" ");
                 number.add(Integer.parseInt(arr[0]));
                 firstWord.add(arr[1]);
                 rest.add(s.substring(arr[0].length() + arr[1].length() + 1));
             }
             finishRead = true;
         } catch (Exception e) {
             System.out.println(e);
         }

         return finishRead;

   }
}
```

This is the dummy streets.txt file I used

```
 1 North East Baker St
 890 North Sonoita Ave
 180 South Swan Rd
```

Comment: Instead of an array could I use a stack or a queue to store the information?

Comment: Of course yes. For queues use LinkedLists. [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/2709249/5850835) you can get some idea on how to use them.

Comment: Thanks I think this really helped. Always have trouble with text files and the such.

Comment: Glad to help you. One advice. If you're not using an IDE, start using one. Do more coding in files and directories. It'll be very easy for you to get an idea and learn. Cheers